# Using CIVICRM API can I get both mobile and phone number?

Tags: contacts, api

I am trying to work out how to call both a phone number and a mobile number using the API. I am in civicrm/api and can get one or the other but not both. Can anyone suggest a solution!?

Thanks
Caroline

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can get both Phone and Mobile in a single API call as below

```
    $result = civicrm_api3('Phone', 'get', [
  'sequential' => 1,
  'contact_id' => 203,
  'phone_type_id' => ['IN' => ["Phone", "Mobile"]],
]);
```

I have created the test example against https://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org

I guess this helps !!!

Thanks

Comment: Brill! Thank you! That works :)